# Partition and Install question

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, gparted

Today I finally got around to getting ready to install Ubuntu on my laptop but the process has not been going the same as my laptop went...

I have two questions and will ask one by one...

**(1)** Install
When I went to install and got to "Installation Type" it does not have the install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I read somewhere that the partition size of Windows if it takes up the whole space it might not find Windows on there.

**(2)** Partition - When I go to resize the Windows 10 partition in gParted it does not let me shrink it, I know there is a way to do it but I completely forget. I don't want to mess this up and I need to take a backup of both computers as well.

[Installation Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZTmH.png)

[gParted Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZvHA.png)

[gParted Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS6j4.png)

Any solutions/advice would help a lot!
Thanks, Jason

Comment: I notice the exclamation mark next to the NTFS partition in your GParted screenshot. It may be useless, but can you please update your post and include the error that it show? It might give some clues. It definitely doesn't seem to be a mounting issue though.

Comment: If the *file-system* contained on sda2 is unclean (eg. hibernate/fast-boot is enabled), you won't be able to touch/re-size that partition until it's made clean (ie. data is moved out of fastboot/hibernate & written to file-system normally).  You also didn't provide release details of the Ubuntu you're trying to install.

Comment: Yes, I just updated it.

Comment: Also, in addition to guiverc's suggestion, can you try and install the packages it is complaining about? If they are already installed, then no worries but it at least eliminates 1 thing that GParted is complaining about..

Comment: The package it is referring to should be installed.

Comment: It is usually safer to use Windows tools on Windows partitions.

Answer (score 1):

GParted should be able to resize NTFS partitions, but to avoid trouble, I recommend letting Windows handle those. Shrink the Windows partition inside Windows itself. Here's how you can do it: https://www.diskpart.com/articles/shrink-c-drive-3889.html